# Next tab with button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I have the body form HTML code

```
<body>
<div id="page-content" class="header-clear">

    <div id="page-content-scroll"><!--Enables this element to be scrolled --> 



            <div class="content padding-content-tab">
                <div id="test-tab">
                    <div class="row">
                        <ul class="tabs padding-tab">
                            <div class="col-xs-4 orange-tab current text-center" data-tab="tabs-1">
                                <li class="tab-link" ><a href="#tabs-1">Step 1</a></li>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4 orange-tab text-center" data-tab="tabs-2">
                                <li class="tab-link" ><a href="#tabs-2">Step 2</a></li>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4 orange-tab text-center" data-tab="tabs-3">
                                <li class="tab-link" ><a href="#tabs-3">Step 3</a></li>
                            </div>

                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div id="tabs-1" class="tab-content current">
                        <div class="tab-elements">

                            <div class="text-center"> 
                                <button id="next_button" name="next_button" class="next-button">Next</button> 


                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="tabs-2" class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-elements">
                            dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
                            nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="tabs-3" class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-elements">
                           a commodo consequat.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

And here is my JS

```
    $('#next_button').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $('ul.tabs div.orange-tab').attr('data-tab');

        $('ul.tabs div.orange-tab').removeClass('current');
        $('div.tab-content').removeClass('current');

        $('ul.tabs div.orange-tab').addClass('current');
        $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
    });
```

That's how i've tried to change the tab but won't work. What any solution can I try? I want to press the button 'Next' and to change the tab. I want a simple solution but to work.

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle or a url where the code has been deployed

Answer (score 2):

here is the solution:

```
<script>
$(function(){

    $('#nexttab').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#mytabs a[href="#second"]').tab('show');
    })

})
</script>
<div class="container">

    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul id="mytabs" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li class="active">
          <a href="#first" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              <icon class="fa fa-home"></icon> Step 1
          </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#second" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
          <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Step 2
          </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#third" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Step 3
          </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="first">
          <h2>First tab</h2>
          <button type="button" id="nexttab" class="btn btn-primary">Set second tab</button>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="second">
          <h2>Second tab</h2>
          <p>  dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
                            nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="third">
          <h2>Third tab</h2>
          <p> a commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first `find` the current selected tab which has `class` as `current` and then `find` `next` tab in the line as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#next_button').click(function() {
    //first find the current selected tab and find next tab in the line as follows,
    var nextTab = $('ul.tabs div.orange-tab.current').next();

    //remove selected from current / all
    $('ul.tabs div.orange-tab').removeClass('current');
    $('div.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    //set it as selected
    nextTab.addClass('current');
    //to show the content 
    $('div[id='+nextTab.data('tab')+']').addClass('current');
    // or this should to work
    //$('div[id='+nextTab.attr('data-tab')+']').addClass('current');
  });
});
```

Comment: Hmm..I don't know why but it removes all my tabs..and not going to next tab..:(

Comment: It works with the tab..but now with the content..it's not showing..content

Comment: Works perfect here! But now i've tried to put the same button on tab 2...to change on tab 3..but here won't work

Comment: @Whicas69 this is a new question altogether. However the button should be out of any tab. Based on button click change the tab.

Comment: @Whicas69 then you need to add buttons with unique id and add events and handler to go to next. Generally next button should be kept outside of tab to switch over to next. same goes for previous.

Comment: Ok, and how need to looks my code if the next button goes outside of tab ...to work for all tabs?

Comment: yes, only one button next and onclick move to next. enough i think

Comment: @Whicas69 accept answer if fixed your initial issue. let me know otherwise

Answer (score 0):

With the following code you can add tabs and keep clicking to change the tab:

javascript:

```
$('#next_button').click(function(e){
    var tab_id = Number($(e.target).closest('div.tab-content').attr('data-id'));
    var currentTabId = Number($('ul.tabs div.orange-tab.current').attr('data-tabid'));
    var tabAmount = $('ul.tabs div.orange-tab').length;
    var nextTabId = (currentTabId == tabAmount ? 1 : currentTabId +1);

    $('ul.tabs div.orange-tab').fadeOut().removeClass('current');
    $('div.tab-content').fadeOut().removeClass('current');

    $('ul.tabs div.orange-tab[data-tabid="' + nextTabId + '"]').addClass('current').fadeIn();
    $('div[data-id="' + nextTabId + '"]').addClass('current').fadeIn();
});
```

html:

```
<div id="page-content" class="header-clear">
    <div id="page-content-scroll"><!--Enables this element to be scrolled -->
        <div class="content padding-content-tab">
            <div id="test-tab">
                <div class="row">
                    <ul class="tabs padding-tab">
                        <div style="display:block;" class="col-xs-4 orange-tab text-center current" data-tabid="1">
                            <li class="tab-link" ><a href="#tabs-1">Step 1</a></li>
                        </div>
                        <div style="display:none;" class="col-xs-4 orange-tab text-center" data-tabid="2">
                            <li class="tab-link" ><a href="#tabs-2">Step 2</a></li>
                        </div>
                        <div style="display:none;" class="col-xs-4 orange-tab text-center" data-tabid="3">
                            <li class="tab-link" ><a href="#tabs-3">Step 3</a></li>
                        </div>
                      </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div style="display:block;" data-id="1" class="tab-content current">
                        <div class="tab-elements">
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display:none;" data-id="2" class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-elements">
                            dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
                            nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display:none;" data-id="3" class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-elements">
                           a commodo consequat.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <button id="next_button" name="next_button" class="next-button">Next</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the elements should point to their next element. here is the code

```
enter code here $('#next_button').click(function() {
    var tab_id = $('ul.tabs .orange-tab.current').attr('data-tab');
    var first = $('ul.tabs .orange-tab:first').attr('data-tab');


    $current = $('ul.tabs div.orange-tab.current').removeClass('current').next();
    $currentTabContent = $('#' + tab_id).removeClass('current').next();

    if ($current.length) {
        $current.addClass('current');
        $currentTabContent.addClass('current');
    } else {
        $('ul.tabs div.orange-tab:first').addClass('current');
        $("#" + first).addClass('current');
    }
```

});

working fiddle [a link] (https://jsfiddle.net/yonashailug/a8n3kdus/)